# Typescript - Type Guard Issue - Make some properties required

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I want to make the p1 property a required property when it passes typeGuard, but I have no idea how to define the red square box. Does anyone know?
[image]

typescript code is below

```
type T = {p1?: string; p2?:number; p3?: boolean}
const t: T = {p1: '1'};

function typeGuard<T extends object, Key extends keyof T>(t: T, key: Key): t is T & {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} {
  return t[key] !== undefined;
}

if (typeGuard(t, 'p1')){
  t.
}
```

Comment: FWIW: You can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mxq8ZW). Be sure to read about the compiler option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trivially implement a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to verify the presence of a key in an object by using a few built-in type utilities:

- [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)
- [`Required<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)
- [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

The function looks like this:

```ts
function hasKey<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Partial<Record<K, any>>>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
): obj is T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
  return key in obj;
}
```

Using it with the example data in your question looks like this:

```ts
type Example = {
  p1?: string;
  p2?: number;
  p3?: boolean;
};

const example: Example = { p1: "1" };

if (hasKey(example, "p1")) {
  example
//^? const example: Example & Required<Pick<Example, "p1">>

  example.p1
        //^? (property) p1: string
  example.p2
        //^? (property) p2?: number | undefined
  example.p3
        //^? (property) p3?: boolean | undefined
}
```

However, I'm not sure there's a great deal of value in such a function. The idiomatic inline expression — which uses the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) — is syntactically shorter and produces the same result:

> See in the TS Handbook: [*The `in` operator narrowing*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)

```ts
if ("p1" in example) {
  example
//^? const example: Example & Required<Pick<Example, "p1">>

  example.p1
        //^? (property) p1: string
  example.p2
        //^? (property) p2?: number | undefined
  example.p3
        //^? (property) p3?: boolean | undefined
}
```

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcDSBTAngHk0WwA8pswATdRABQCc4AHbeqXHXAGkQBViyFanVRsYqADb4AStghx6lQj1RhcAPk0AKAFCJEcAEYArAFx8uexAGs85zJYCU5o8cQwa-AGSJZARxAYemwlWhgIa3xeHkxNRABvK2CoEHokW1x3JFcAbh0AXx0ddhZEAFESVABbJglsRABeBKsmAEYAfnN0KHoYMABzPP0mACZOxDAQKsNWIcQmAGZxwzg4OtU8-LydeTBugWra7HMKw7rGhPnW8wAiVpvELaKYYEQtNCw8LVIz7B4bto3RyOZr6H41Oo6AD0UIAeu0imDKhDsAA6NpWfRYxAw+FWcFHdEjTHYnFwhFI37ohYk7G4hGFHQvN4A+5ZA4okGJSko6HkxEcwkY0lY+n45FC4ki-RinlCmnSsl4wpAA)

---

Note that things become a bit more complicated if `undefined` is a union member for the optional value. Be sure to read about the compiler option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) to understand more. (The playground link above is configured with that option enabled.)